# How should I get AES to work on strings of arbitrary length in Java?

Tags: java, aes

I've been reading up on AES for the past 2 hours, and this is what I've got to show for it so far:

```
static String decrypt(byte[] encrypted){
    try{
        Key aesKey = new SecretKeySpec(System.getenv("CRYPTO_KEY").getBytes(), "AES");
        // The key is 32 bytes long.
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, aesKey);
        return new String(cipher.doFinal(encrypted));
    } catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("decrypt() failed.");
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}

static byte[] encrypt(String plaintext){
    try{
        Key aesKey = new SecretKeySpec(System.getenv("CRYPTO_KEY").getBytes(), "AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, aesKey);
        return cipher.doFinal(plaintext.getBytes());
    } catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("encrypt() failed.");
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

I know that AES operates on blocks of 16 bytes each, but I don't think I can guarantee that my input strings will be 16 bytes or less. Is there an easy way to get this cipher to work on arbitrary-length strings? Or do I just have to break up the input into 16-byte blocks and run each one through manually?

Comment: That's what modes of operation (CBC) do for you.

Comment: Actually the padding is solving that for you. If your cleartext is not a multiple of the ciphers blocksize (16 bytes), the padding will fill up the remaining bytes. There's different padding schemes (PKCS5, PKCS7) which solve this problem differently.

Comment: @SLaks CBC mode has nothing to do with handling arbitrary data lengths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding" allows data of an arbitrary length. The question code should properly handle arbitrary length data.

Yes, AES is a block based cipher but that does not mean that higher layers can not use it to process data of arbitrary length. In this case `Cipher` is such a higher level implementation.

First the implementation makes multiple calls to the underlying block cipher as necessary to process the entire data passed to it.

Second padding such as PKCS#7 (many times erroneously called PKCS#5) adds padding bytes to the last block to bring the data up to a multiple of the block size.

In the same manor these higher layers can implement several modes such as CBC, ECB, CTS, CTR and etc. CTS and CTR are example modes that use another method of handling arbitrary data lengths without adding padding.

Comment: The streaming cipher variants are worthy of a mention.